# where does helm 3 get its cluster location from?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have installed Helm 3 binary locally on my Mac. I understand that Helm 3 does not use Tiller on the Kubernetes cluster. How do I configure Helm 3 to know where to find my cluster? I have looked all through the documentation but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured it out:

Helm uses KubeConfig file.